# Calculating permutations of a String where preceding characters matter

Tags: java, string, logic, permutation

I have an initial string:
`BBBCCC`.

Where `B is +1` and `C is -1`

Rule: A `C` cannot be placed if the cumulative values of `B's and C's` preceding it will result in a negative number.

For instance, `BCCBBC` cannot work since we have `+1 - 1 (0) -1 (-1) +1 (0) +1 (1) -1 (0)` since it results in a negative number during the accumulation.

This means that accepted permutations would be the following:

`BBBCCC`
`BBCBCC`
`BBCCBC`
`BCBBCC`
`BCBCBC`

I have a few ideas of code but am not sure what a good way to start this is with a given calculated string of `N` initial `B`s would be.

I am attempting to implement this in Java.

What I have thus far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static ArrayList<String> pathPermutations = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numToEnter;
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a node: ");
        numToEnter = myScanner.nextInt();
        calculatePermutations(numToEnter);
    }


    public static void calculatePermutations(int nodeNum){
        pathPermutations.clear();
        pathPermutations.add(constructInitialPath(nodeNum));

        System.out.println(pathPermutations.get(0));
    }
    public static String constructInitialPath(int nodeNum){
        String pathString = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<nodeNum*2;i++){
            if(i<nodeNum){
                pathString+="B";
            }else{
                pathString+="C";
            }
        }
        return pathString;
    }

    public void populatePermutations(String s){
        int length = s.length()/2;
        int accumulator = 0;
        int nodeIntercepts = 0;
        String newPermutation = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<length*2;i++){
            if(i==0){
                newPermutation+="B";
                accumulator++;
            }else if(i>0 && accumulator>){

            }
        }


    }
}
```

How can I manipulate the `populatePermutations` method to take in the initial string of `BBBCCC` (or N arbitrary number of B's/C's sorted) and recursively calculate the substrings according to my rule stated before.

For instance:

Step 1. `BBBCCC`
Step 2. `BBCBCC`, etc etc.

Comment: There I added the attempts I have made. I am trying to take in an initial string and do some population to an `ArrayList` of strings by manipulating that initial string and creating the permutations given my rules stated before.

Comment: Your code has "E" and "S", but your description has `B` and `C`. And there is still no question anywhere.

Comment: I have changed that. If you would check into that. And my question is, what is a good way to manipulate the populatePermutations method by implementing the initial string and calculating all sub strings based off what I have said before.

Comment: For this kind of logic, you'd need a [recursive method](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-recursion/).

Comment: Put your question into the question, not is a comment.

Comment: Right. I was thinking of feeding back the resulting string back into the populatePermutations method, but I am not sure how to guarantee properly that all preceding strings are not going to result in that "negative" value as mentioned by my rule.

Comment: Sure I will. Then please remove your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive method. The method would take string built so far, sum of letters so far, and target length as parameters.

- If target length reached, print result and return.
- Append a +1 letter, then call itself.
- If allowed, append a -1 letter instead, then call itself.

---

Or instead of target length, the numbers of +1 and -1 letters left to append.

Comment: would we be necessarily appending letters or would we be manipulating letter positions in the string's character array?

Comment: Ah I see. I will try that out.

Comment: I think what I am confused on is, are we not using our initial string of `BBBCCC` as a base parameter to be entered into our recursive  method call?

Comment: You don't really care if the initial string is `BBBCCC` or `BCCBBC` or `CCCBBB`, as long as there are at least as many `B`'s as `C`'s. Count them, validate `countB >= countC` then start recursion with `permutate("", 0, countB, countC)`.

Comment: Ah I understand. I will try this out and post back if I am successful. Thank you for your help.